# segue failing when trying to pass a value to a function

Tags: swift

I'm trying to send a value from one ViewController to another but I'm getting an break point error.

here is the VC I'm trying to pass a value from.

```
 class vcImageList: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
 .....
 ........
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier? == "fullImage" {
           (segue.destinationViewController as vcFullImage).test("aaaaa")
    }
```

The VC I'm trying to get the value from.

```
class vcFullImage: UIViewController{
   var imageImdex: Int = 0
   var objectID:NSManagedObjectID = NSManagedObjectID()       

   func test (a: String){
      println(a)
   }
}
```

Comment: A break point error? It sounds like you accidentally set a break point. Right-click on the arrow and select Delete Breakpoint.

Comment: I wish i had a break point set

Comment: So what is exactly the error message?

Comment: Please don't call your view controller subclass `vcFullImage`. The names of types in Swift should begin with a capital letter. A much better name is `FullImageViewController`. To me, `vcFullImage` looks like the name of an instance, which is potentially confusing.

Comment: Unless you have multiple `vcFullImage` instances as segue destinations, you might want to say something like `if let fullImage = segue.destinationViewController as? vcFullImage { fullImage.test("aaaa") }`